# call dotnet core action by ajax working with visual studio but not working after hosting on iis get status code 404

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-core, iis

call dotnet core action by ajax working with visual studio but not working after hosting on iis get status code 404

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/ApiCommon/AutoComplete",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item, value: item };
                }))
            },

        })
```

and this is my action

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AutoComplete([FromQuery]AutoComp autoComp)
    {
        return new JsonResult("Test");
    }
```

Comment: What are the URLs of the pages this code runs on? Can you share the network log (even just from chrome dev tools) too see what it is trying to hit and where it 404s, or doesn't, in both environments?

Comment: You need to make sure the URL is correct. First you can check the request sent by ajax in development mode of browser to get the sub status code. Second, try to enter the url of action in browser directly so that you can make sure if the correct url can access the action. If the URL is right and action can recevie request, maybe something wrong with ajax.

Comment: Check the browser console and see if you find any error or message there?